# How to query the unification type to ghci?

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, unification

It is possible to query ghci for an unification type?

For example, if I want to know the type of the unification between `(Int -> Bool)` and `(a -> Bool)` how can I query this to ghci?

What I'm trying to solve is the exercise 13.23 from third edition of [Haskell: The Craft of Functional Programming](http://www.haskellcraft.com).

> How can you use the Haskell system to check whether two type expressions 
>   are unifiable, and if so what is their unification? Hint: you can make dummy 
>   definitions in Haskell in which the defined value, zircon say, is equated with 
>   itself:
>
> ```
> zircon = zircon
> ```
>
> Values defined like this can be declared to have any type you wish.

Thanks,
Sebastián.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use [`asTypeOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aasTypeOf)`:: a -> a -> a`. As a function, `asTypeOf` isn't very interesting, but its type is nice: it forces its two arguments and its return type to unify. So:

```
> :t asTypeOf (undefined :: Int -> Bool) (undefined :: a -> Bool)
asTypeOf (undefined :: Int -> Bool) (undefined :: a -> Bool)
  :: Int -> Bool
```

So you can see that those two types unified to `Int -> Bool`. For a slightly more interesting example, let's unify `Maybe a` and `f (Bool, c)`:

```
> :t asTypeOf (undefined :: Maybe a) (undefined :: f (Bool, c))
asTypeOf (undefined :: Maybe a) (undefined :: f (Bool, c))
  :: Maybe (Bool, c)
```

On the other hand, for the purpose of exercises, I encourage you to attempt to do the unification by hand. It's not hard, once you get the hang of it, and is a skill that you will use over and over.

Comment: it is also possible to use list constructor `:t [undefined :: Maybe a, undefined :: f (Bool, c)]`